# what is the android core library called?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, libraries, jcenter

I'm trying to get a package to have Android's libraries as one of it's dependencies and I know those libraries are already available to me; I just don't know how to identify it!

P.S. I'm using Gradle(Jcenter) in Android Studio, and the package in-question is an ordinary Java package I just want linked with an Android app.

Here is my build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.appengine:gradle-appengine-plugin:1.9.28'
}
}

repositories {
    jcenter();
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'appengine'

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7

dependencies {
    appengineSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.28'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints:1.9.28'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints-deps:1.9.28'
    compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
    compile 'com.googlecode.objectify:objectify:5.1.9'
    compile 'com.ganyo:gcm-server:1.0.2'
    compile ''//<--What do I put here to get Android core-package??
 }

appengine {
     downloadSdk = true
     appcfg {
         oauth2 = true
     }
     endpoints {
         getClientLibsOnBuild = true
         getDiscoveryDocsOnBuild = true
     }
 }
```

Comment: Sorry but your question doesn't make sense for me. What do you try? You need to download the SDK with the SDK manager. There are now 23 major versions of the SDK so far.

Comment: Your question is unclear.

Comment: @rekire, I think what he is trying to mean is that he wants to include the android libraries into his own package.

Comment: @SajibAcharya like using activity transitions on Gingerbread? That is impossible.

Comment: You mean support libraries? They're not on jcenter. You download them via SDK Manager. It's `Android support repository` and `Google repository` for Google Play services. I think.

Comment: @rekire, No, like he probably has some package of his own, `com.example.something` and he wants to include one version of the Android SDK into this package of his own. This is what I get from `I'm trying to get a package to have Android's libraries as one of it's dependencies`, not sure.

Comment: What are you doing? I mean you try to use servlets in a native android app? That doesn't make sense. You might want to apply the 'com.android.application' plugin to build your project.